$\vec{\nabla}×\vec{E}=-\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$. If i were to apply this equation to a single conducting loop, is field non-conservative?
$\vec{\nabla}×\vec{E}=-\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$. Let's say there is a changing magnetic field in the middle of a conducting loop. Let's also say that this loop consists of a two resistors  and a battery. The field produced by the battery is conservative while the field produced by the changing magnetic field isn't. My question is which is which? Is the electric field in Faraday's equation the total electric field or is it just the field produced by the changing magnetic field?

I disagree with the part of your sentence that says "The field produced by the battery is conservative".
The conservative force does not become a source of continuous energy supply.

But $\oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l}=0$ in the absence of the changing magnetic field, which means the electric field is conservative. But the only source of the electric field then is the battery. Therefore, the electric field of the battery is conservative! What is the flaw in my reasoning?

@HEMMI Jack is correct, battery's electric field is nearly electrostatic, thus conservative. The source of energy in circuit powered by a battery isn't the electric field, but chemical transformation inside the battery, which produces net effective force inside the battery, acting against battery's electric field.

@Ján Lalinský, I disagree with you. All components of electric fields should be described in authorised physics textbooks.
Where can I find a chemistry specific electric field? How many electric field components are there in the world?

@Jack, Yes, if the changing magnetic field is zero, then the electric field is conservative. On the other hand, we know that
"Equivalently, if a particle travels in a closed loop, the total work done (the sum of the force acting along the path multiplied by the displacement) by a conservative force is zero."
Wikipedia
So I suspect that "the changing magnetic field is NOT zero in the EMF-generating part of the chemical battery".

@HEMMI you are wrong and Jan is correct. The electrochemistry of batteries are very heavily studied and indeed depends strongly on the chemistry used. If not, people would not be fighting over Lithium.

As you wrote it, the Faraday law involves net electric and net magnetic field.
The same equation holds also for the non-conservative component of that net electric field $\mathbf E_i$ (while the magnetic field on the right-hand side is the same).
Thus we have both
$$
\nabla\times\mathbf E = -\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t}
$$
and also
$$
\nabla\times\mathbf E_i = -\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t}.
$$
This is so because $\mathbf E=\mathbf 
 E_c+\mathbf E_i$, and curl of $\mathbf E_c$, the conservative component of net electric field, is zero: $\nabla\times \mathbf  E_c = 0$.

And the voltage drop across the resistor R calculated through ohms' law IR is gonna equal in this case to $\int_{a}^{b} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l}$ where $\vec{E}$ is the total electric field?

@Jack It depends on what you mean by "voltage drop". If you mean difference of electric potential (this is how voltage is used in theory of circuits), then voltage is $\int_a^b\mathbf {E}_c \cdot d\mathbf s$. Ohm's law does not hold, because potential difference is not the only thing acting on current. We have to use the generalized Ohm law, which says $\int_a^b \mathbf E \cdot d\mathbf s = RI$, while the left-hand side is not voltage in the above sense, but instead is sum of potential difference and induced EMF in the resistor.
